# Why cannot map localization xml by remotely run exe on powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to remotely launch xxx.exe -argument via powershell, xxx.exe will load/map customized localization.xml(need to put localization.xml and xxx.exe at the same folder) and display its related name. The expected output is as below:

```
Description : [0076] HP 534M DP Virtual Bus Device #76
Link Type   : iSCSI
Link State  : Down
MAC/WWN     : 2C-44-FD-8D-72-3D
PF Number   : 1
Description : [0073] HP 534M DP Virtual Bus Device #73
Link Type   : Ethernet
Link State  : Down
MAC/WWN     : 2C-44-FD-8D-72-3C
```

It works fine if I simply run it on the remote side

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& "C:\path\xxx.exe" -showadapter}
```

But it cannot map localizaion.xml if I remotely run xxx.cli

```
param([String]$IP, [String]$Username, [String]$Password)
$secpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential     ($Username,$secpwd)
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $IP -Credential $cred
Invoke-Command -Session $session{& "C:\path\xxx.exe" -showadapter}
```

and its output is,

```
No localization entry -  : [0076] HP 534M DP Virtual Bus Device #76  
No localization entry -  : iSCSI
No localization entry -  : Down
No localization entry -  : 2C-44-FD-8D-72-3D
No localization entry -  : 1
No localization entry -  : [0073] HP 534M DP Virtual Bus Device #73
No localization entry -  : Ethernet
No localization entry -  : Down
No localization entry -  : 2C-44-FD-8D-72-3C
```

The partial content of localization.xml is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="SHiFT-JIS"?>
<localization>
    <usermessage id ="0x0001" message = "Description"/>
    <usermessage id ="0x0002" message = "Link Type"/>
    ...
<localization>
```

I'm so confused why xxx.cli can automatically map/load localization.xml if I run it on remote side but it failed to be mapping once I remotely run it.

Is there any hint/solution for it?

Huge thanks!!

Comment: What's the `xxx.exe`, some kind of device management tool? What locales are supported?

Comment: xxx.exe is command line file that we create for user. The general use is xxx.exe -argument (such like xxx.exe -settcpip)

Comment: So it's a custom application? Seems like the locale detection process doesn't quite work on remote session. Ask its developers how it figures out which locale is being used.

Comment: Yep. It's custom application and me and other team member develop its function. Once users put localization.xml and xxx.exe at the same folder and xxx.exe is able to automatically map its message by related message id. The weird thing now is, how can't it map it if I run xxx.exe remotely via powershell.

Comment: What toolchain and framework is being used? .Net? Java? gcc? Python?

Comment: it's c++ on vc2012(vc110) and .NET4.0. We generate ooo.dll and xxx.exe. Once we enter command by using xxx.exe -argument, generally, it will automatically load localization.xml and find its message, then output result.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your program is attempting to load an XML from the same directory in which the program resides. Based on that, it sounds like when in the remote session the script block is being executed from a different working directory.

I am not sure how your custom program is written. For example, does it identify the full path where it is being executed from or uses a relative path, so I would try changing to that directory first and then execute your program:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session {cd C:\path; & .\xxx.exe -showadapter}
```

Comment: Hi Jon, thx for ur suggestion. But it still return No localizaton Entry which means still don't load/map message name in localization.xml

Comment: @T.Eddy. Can you add some verbose messages to your custom application to indicate whether it is even locating the XML file? I am trying to reproduce with another exe like plink.exe but it is able to access a file in the same directory just fine in a remote session as long as I change to that directory.